# Get updated files without runnint generate again?

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js

My nuxt build takes 10min and it is very annoying when I have to run nuxt generate for every little change (e.g. a tiny hotfix on the site).

Is it possible to prevent this? I.e. nuxt dev is apparently able to change the file in my browser on the fly. Can I also have it change the file in the dist folder, so I can deploy it without having to run generate again?

Comment: If you use universal.mode you don't need generate

Comment: @Aldarund but I have to build again for deployment

Comment: yes, and how long takes build? Because build and generate different things.

Comment: @Aldarund build and generate both take 10min. generate essentially runs build and then does some additional (less demanding) work. But I have already found a solution:
https://cmty.app/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/c7664